# RecyclerView cannot be found

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I just started to try to use the RecyclerView. I added some lines into the build.grandle but I always get many error messages telling me:
' error: cannot find symbol'
' error: package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist'
and I do not understand why I am getting these error messages. Here you see the code of my grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.td.barapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        viewBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
}
```

I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful.

Update: I think I have a problem with AndroidX. I migrated to it by using Refactor-->Migrate to AndroidX in Android studio but I do not know how I should change my posted grandle.build file. At the moment in my grandle file I have some libararies like " implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' and I get the warning and error message: "This support library should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (28) " But when I use " implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0'" I also get an error message :"All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable..

Here you see a screenshot of the marked lines in the Build grandle file:[image: Screenshot Android Studio of the build grandle file] How do I have to change these lines in order to use AndroidX? I'd be happy for your help because I am stuck on that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to gradle dependencies

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
```

Also make sure these lines are present in your gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vansh. Why do I have to do this? I already have entered the line 'implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0''

Comment: That is for the support library (pre-androidx). As you are using androidx, you need to add the androidx dependency.

Comment: Thanks Vansh for your answer. I am not using androidx (I do not even know what this is)

Comment: Your question contains the following error: package androidx.recyclerview.widget

Comment: Thanks Vansh for your answer. When I use your code I cannot even sync the project and I get the error :ERROR: This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks Vansh for your comment. Now I get the following error: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not set unknown property 'enableJetifier' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: I put it on the wrong grandle. Now I put android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true on the correct grandle but I get many errors that I have not got before

Comment: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\T.D\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\173de8c433dc5f4aca0638778cb887e6\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":442}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\T.D\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\173de8c433dc5f4aca0638778cb887e6\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214936/discussion-between-vansh-arora-and-vanessaf).

Comment: Hi Vansh. When I use the code you suggested "android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true" I get error messages because of "android.support." I think. In my grandle build file the "android.support.27" libraries are marked as an error. How do I have to change the build file?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

And y delete 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:..., because you've already import it with

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

Comment: Thanks Mexi for your answer. If I use your code I get many errors that I did not get before even in the classes. The errors are of the type 'Cannot ressolve symbol AppCompatActivity, LinearLayoutManager, RecyclerView, setContentView etc

Answer (score 0):

> ' error: cannot find symbol' ' error: package
>   androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist' and I do not understand
>   why I am getting these error

It seems that you're using `RecyclerView` from `androidx` in your layout with `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`; but you need to add support library `RecyclerView` which is `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

this requires to include `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'` in your gradle module

Comment: Thanks Zain. I think I have a problem with integrating AndroidX. How do I have to change the grandle to do this (or do I have to do something else to integrate Android X)?

Comment: Hi @VanessaF you can add it to in the `dependencies {}` that you provided to the question body; if you want to migrate to androidx, then go to Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX .. but make sure you backup your project before migration

Comment: Thanks Zain for your comment. In my grandle file I have some libararies like " implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' and I get the warning and error message: "This support library should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (28) " But when I use " implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0'" I also get an error message :"All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable...

Comment: @VanessaF thanks for replying back, you should unify all the versions to be the same as the `compileSdkVersions`; in your case you are using version `27.0.0` and you can apply it to the recyclerview dependency as `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0' `

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have an issue in your layout file, try to remove the widget and add again just type 'recyclerview' and android studio will complete the reference for you.

**You can use this quick-setting available in android studio, it will migrate your project to AndroidX automatically --**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anuj. I think I have a problem with integrating AndroidX. How do I have to change the grandle to do this (or do I have to do something else to integrate Android X)?

Comment: Updated my answer, I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Anuj for your comment. In my grandle file I have some libararies like "    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' and I get the warning and error message:
"This support library should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (28) " But when I use "    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0'" I also get an error message :"All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable...